# Nesting template strings in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, template-literals

I'm trying to retrieve a variable from an object.

```
cell: (row: any) => `${row.testcolumn}`
```

My only issue is that I don't know what 'testcolumn' is ahead of time as I'm doing this dynamically.  I'm not sure what to do, and the nested template string strategy I'm attempting will not compile.

```
cell: (row: any) => `${row.(`${varString}`)}`
```

I've also tried just using the variable name instead of nesting a template string, but that just looks for the varString value in the object, which doesn't exist.  Is there any way I can use a nested literal to substitute the string value into the template literal and it still look for row.testcolumn instead of row.varString?

Comment: Would `cell: (row: any) => \`${row[varString]}\`` work? Maybe I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is same for template literals as for regular JS. Object properties can be retrieved dynamically with bracket notation, `row[varString]`.

It will be:

```
cell: (row: any) => `${row[varString]}`
```

Comment: Still pretty new to this stuff, I appreciate it!