# ES6 Computed Property & nested template literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, literals

Please take a look at the following code:

```
const config = {
  prefix: 'MYAPP',
  MYAPP_HOST: '1',
  MYAPP_HOST: '2',
  [ this.prefix + '_HOST' ]: 'localhost',
}

console.log(`${config.MYAPP_HOST}`)
console.log(`${config.${config.prefix}_HOST}`)
```

What's the proper way to make both outputs to print `localhost`?

I know one way to make

```
  [ this.prefix + '_HOST' ]: 'localhost',
```

working is to define `this.prefix` as an function, so it becomes:

```
  [ this_prefix() + '_HOST' ]: 'localhost',
```

However, I'm hoping that, because the `prefix` belongs to `const config`, so that it could be defined *within* `const config`, not *outside* of it.

As for `${config.prefix}_HOST`, I'm just trying to construct the string `MYAPP_HOST`, but nested with template literal. Is there any way to make it possible?

**EDIT:**

> *Nested template makes no sense*

while it might not be obvious why I need to do this, because the question has been simplified to *focus on the technique*, here is the a *less simplified version* of what I want. take a look at the following code:

```
const config = {
  prefix: 'MYAPP',
  app: { port: 3000 },
  db: { host: 'localhost', port: 27017, name: 'db' },

  url: function () { return `driver:/${process.env.MYAPP_HOST || this.db.host}:${process.env.MYAPP_PORT || this.db.port}/${process.env.MYAPP_NAME || this.db.name}` },
}
```

and I don't want to use string literal `MYAPP` in the `process.env.MYAPP_...` but want to use the `prefix` variable instead. Makes sense or not aside, this is what I need to do. Now how to do that?

**UPDATE:**

The answers to the above question has been spreading at many places, so here is the concise summary of the solution (to OP):

```
const prefix = 'MYAPP'
const config = {
  prefix,
  MYAPP_HOST: '1',
  MYAPP_HOST: '2',
  [ prefix + '_HOST' ]: 'localhost',
}
console.log(`${config.MYAPP_HOST}`)
console.log(`${config[config.prefix+'_HOST']}`)
```

Thanks everyone, upvoting to your all!

Comment: `config[\`${config.prefix}_HOST\`]`

Comment: @elclanrs, OK. so it is impossible to still define `MYAPP_HOST` within `const config` declaration. Now, how about nested template literal, is it impossible as well?

Comment: I don't know if what you want is possible, but `this` at this time is the one of your context (e.g `window` if from global scope). And instead of a function, you could always use a simple variable `const prefix = "MYAPP", config = {prefix: prefix, [prefix + "_HOST"]: 'localhost'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as nested template literals because it isn't needed. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48797041/3731501), this is achieved with bracket notation, both in template literals and regular JS. It should be:

```
url: function () {
  return `driver:/${process.env[this.prefix + '_HOST'] || this.db.host}:${process.env[this.prefix + '_PORT'] || this.db.port}/${process.env[this.prefix + '_NAME'] || this.db.name}`
}
```

Usually there is even no need for that because this template literal is very confusing and hard to read. The purpose of template literals is to provide well-formatted concatenated strings, and this one defies the purpose.

Such expressions can be seen with temporary variables in properly styled third-party code - and yes, it can be achieved without bracket notation then:

```
url: function () {
  const host = process.env[`${this.prefix}_HOST`] || this.db.host;
  ...
  return `driver:/${host}:${port}/${name}`;
}
```

Nice, clean and requires no enormously long lines that can cause linter errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
const config = {
  prefix: 'MYAPP',
  MYAPP_HOST: '1',
  MYAPP_HOST: '2',
  [ this.prefix + '_HOST' ]: 'localhost',
}
```

Above would not work as in the time of the declaration of `config`, `this.prefix` is `undefined`. You would get something like following if you log `config`. Note `undefined_HOST`.

```
{prefix: "MYAPP", MYAPP_HOST: "2", undefined_HOST: "localhost"}
```

Instead try following, if you really want to do it like that,

```
const config = {
  prefix: 'MYAPP'
}
config[config.prefix+'_HOST']='localhost'
```

Comment: OK. so it is impossible to still define `MYAPP_HOST` within `const config` declaration. Now, how about nested template literal, is it impossible as well?

Comment: @xpt Nested template makes no sense. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796938/nesting-template-strings-in-typescript

Comment: @estus, unfortunately that doesn't answer *my* question.

Comment: @xpt OP had exactly same issue as you did. I've added the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Your original snippet does not work because you cannot [reference properties of the object literal during its definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations) (as @Skyler also explained).

However, it should work perfectly fine inside that `url` *method*. I would write

```
const config = {
  prefix: 'MYAPP',
  app: { port: 3000 },
  db: { host: 'localhost', port: 27017, name: 'db' },
  prefixed_env(name) {
    return process.env[this.prefix+"_"+name];
    // or, with template literals:
    return process.env[`${this.prefix}_${name}`];
  },
  url() {
    const host = this.prefixed_env("HOST") || this.db.host,
          port = this.prefixed_env("PORT") || this.app.port,
          name = this.prefixed_env("NAME") || this.db.name;
    return `driver:/${host}:${port}/${name}`;
  },
};
```

Instead of `this`, you [can also refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this) to `config` directly.